# Finding "Filler" projects for students

Tags: lesson-ideas, project, hardware

Short Summary of the situation:

*I live on the Dutch countryside, here there are several colleges/universities that offer IT degrees (post-secondary vocational education/ Bachelor Degree/Master Degree). But most of those students go west to the city after graduating, creating a knowledge drain on the region while there are companies here that are actually looking for new IT employees.
To combat this local companies (Both companies who do and do not have IT as a core business), Schools and the local government are banding together to create an IT-Hub to bring students and businesses together. In an attempt to keep graduates in the area and to lure more IT-based companies to our region.*

Now here comes the issue, the IT-Hub is supposed to get assignments from the companies so that the students can work on them in a controlled environment. And although we got enough projects for the other fields (Design, web development, software engineering and so on) we are seriously lacking projects/assignments for "IT-Management" (IT-Management is stuff like security, server management, cisco, hardware repair and such).

**Is there some website where I can find filler assignments for them until the companies themselves are able to provide some?(a Course might also work if there are no other options available) Or do any of you have any suggestions?**

Comment: Could this help? https://mobile.twitter.com/AliceRaffaele1/status/1392857916365959168

Comment: Your short summary can be shorter, by not including the words "a short summary". Also, putting this up front makes it harder to read. There is a lot of detail, that we don't yet know the relevance of. Start with the key problem, then add detail.